# Смещение значений в пандас при заданном условии

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Всем здравствуйте.

Имеется таблица

[image: Таблица ВРП]

Требуется сместить ФИКТ_ВРП на одну ячейку вниз, там, где ФИКТ_ВРП равняется 2008 году. То есть если находит совпадение, смещает на единицу вниз.
Знаю что существует функция shift(), но как её применить с условием год=2008 пока не могу сообразить. Кто сталкивался? Можете подсказать?

Заранее благодарен за ответ

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: `ФИКТ_ВРП равняется 2008 году` это как вообще? Значение колонки `ФИКТ_ВРП` такое же, как эта колонка когда колонка Год=2008 или что имеется в виду? А смещение куда - на соседние строки должно наехать или как или где? Ничего непонятно.

Comment: Тут условие если год равняется 2008 происходит сдвиг ФИКТ_ВРП на 1 вниз, при этом всё остальное остаётся